# Why does Redux saves my regex value as an object type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am getting the weirdest behavior. I use a masked input in a form: react-text-mask. Quick example of how a masked input is defined:

```
<MaskedInput
  mask={['(', /[1-9]/, /\d/, /\d/, ')', ' ', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, '-', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/]}
  className="form-control"
  placeholder="Enter a phone number"
  guide={false}
  id="my-input-id"
  onBlur={() => {}}
  onChange={() => {}}
/>
```

For many reasons I save my definition in the Redux state. And use the input as such:

```
<MaskedInput
  placeholder={placeholder} // comes from Redux state
  mask={mask} // comes from Redux state
  className="form-control"
  value={value} // comes from Redux state
  onChange={(e) => handleChange(id, e.target.value)} // triggers action that saves value to Redux
/>
```

The problem comes from me saving the mask in the Redux. The execution follows as such:

1. I register the form element in the state. The action brings the correct format: ["(", /[0-9]/, /\d/, ")", " ", /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, "-", /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/]
2. I expand to check what the Redux has stored, it is modified, but without my input:\
   [image]
3. My input breaks as such:
   [image]

So what seems to me is that redux preforms some kind of data normalisation and updates and regex values stored.

Can you tell me why this happens? If it is a feature, not a bug :D I will reconsider storing my Regex in the Redux.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide the reducer that you use to create the new state with the mask. I think the problem is in there.

Comment: Quote from the top answer: _"No, you should not store function references in the redux store. They are not serializable, and as you mentioned state should be serializable at all time."_

Comment: `/\d/` this is a regex literal that is not serializable. `JSON.stringify(/\d/)` returns `{}`.

Comment: Thanks for all your answers. I understand now, what went wrong :) However can you maybe give me some suggestions how to overcome this problem? Maybe store an id to some local enum? And just read the mask from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't serialize a regex literal and you should not store function references in redux.  your problem is

```
JSON.stringify(/\d/) => {}
```

So your regex literal is never accurately serialized.